# Custom paragraph command, prevent page break

Tags: pdftex, paragraphs

I am using the book class to write a document that will have numbered paragraphs. Wanted the (auto-incremented) paragraph numbers to be bold and centred, then the text below, and the paragraph number to have a label so it can be referenced. Using other people's suggestions, I've got this function/command:

```
\newcounter{para}
\newcommand\mypara[1]{
    \par\refstepcounter{para}\vfill
    \begin{center}\textbf{\thepara}\end{center}\label{#1}
    }
```

and the way I use it in the document is:

```
\mypara{myreference}
This is a nice numbered paragraph. I don't want any braces around the paragraph body, if at all possible.
```

which is working nicely EXCEPT when I use it close to the bottom of the page, in which case it's possible for the bold paragraph number to be on one page, and the text of the paragraph to be on the next. Is it possible to prevent a page break like this? I'm using multicols{2} as well, if that's relevant. Any help appreciated.

Min. example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}  % sets the distance between columns
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{para}
\newcommand\mypara[1]{
    \par\refstepcounter{para}\vfill
    \begin{center}\textbf{\thepara}\end{center}\label{#1}
    }

\title{Minimum working example}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    % main part of the document:

    \mainmatter
    \begin{multicols}{2}

        \mypara{ref1}
        \blindtext

        \mypara{ref2}
        \blindtext

        \mypara{ref3}
        \blindtext

        \mypara{ref4}
        \blindtext

    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered to change your `\label{#1}` to also include something that will help you with easy identification? For example `\label{par:#1}`. This will help if you ever have a chapter and a paragraph with the same name, but need to reference both on separate occasions.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I will consider doing that if I can get a viable fix to this problem to proceed with my document

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using `\vfill`? [Since removing it results in this, which looks better IMO.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtt3q.png)

Comment: Thanks. I was only using vfill because a previous google suggestion for this custom paragraph function had the vfill in. I agree it looks better without the vfill. Although on my live document I still have the same overall problem!

Comment: Without `\vfill` put the whole stuff in a box, eg.g., a `\parbox` or a `minipage`, or to use other that an invisible unbreakable box, maybe you would like the tcolorbox package (that can numbered and referenced,  among a lot of another features, it have an excellent manual) but personally I will use sections as in the Jhor's answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard sectioning mechanism, suitably adapted.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}  % sets the distance between columns
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{para}
\newcommand\mypara[1]{%
  \@startsection{para}{1}{\z@}%
    {-\topsep}%
    {\topsep}%
    {\normalfont\bfseries\centering}%
    {}\label{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\myparamark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname format#1\endcsname
    \csname format#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\formatpara}{\thepara}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Minimum working example}
\pagestyle{empty}

% main part of the document:

\mainmatter

\begin{multicols}{2}

\mypara{ref1}
%A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more\\
A line more

\blindtext

\mypara{ref2}
\blindtext

\mypara{ref3}
\blindtext

\mypara{ref4}
\blindtext

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

You can check that uncommenting the first `A line more`, section 4 will be pushed to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `\vfill` as pointed by @Flexo013 actually fixes your local problem.
I would however provide another solution, that IMO is more efficient.

First, if you don use `\chapter` (and have no `\frontmatter`) you definitely don't need the features of the `book` class. Second, if you wish to be able to produce a TOC and bookmarks, your `\para` won't do the job.

Let me switch to `article` and modify the top-level sectioning command `\section` by the use of a sinle line `\titleformat` from `titlesec` package. 
The MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{1cm}  % sets the distance between columns
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\tableofcontents

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering\bfseries}{\thesection}{0pt}{\@gobble{#1}}[\label{par:#1}]
\makeatother

    \section{foo}
    \blindtext

    \section{bar}      
    In \S\ref{par:foo} we said that \ldots

    \section{foo2}      
     \blindtext

    \section{bar2}      
    In §\,\ref{par:foo2} we will say that \ldots

    \section{foo3}      
    \blindtext

    \section{bar3}      
     \blindtext

    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this and see how it works

Comment: In this answer I didn't really addressed the problem of pagebreak between title (in your case the number) and the body  of the paragraph. In principle, the standard mechanism of LaTeX for handling the sectioning commend should avoid 90% of such breaks. If some still occur, one could tweak the penalties.